# MYSQL: Friend list with detail & unread message count

Tags: mysql

I am working on chat system and want to list friend details with unread message count.

Tables structure likes below

**users**

```
id
name
```

**friends**

```
id
sender_id
recipient_id
```

**messages**

```
id
from_id
to_id
read_at
```

Fetching user's friends data with detail using below query

```
(SELECT U.id, U.name 
   FROM users U LEFT JOIN friends F 
     ON U.id = F.recipient_id 
  WHERE F.sender_id = 2) 
UNION 
(SELECT U.id, U.name 
   FROM users U LEFT JOIN friends F 
     ON U.id = F.sender_id 
  WHERE F.recipient_id = 2) 
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Query gives me perfect result, return user 2's friends but i want unread message count (WHERE read_at = NULL) with the list of friend. How can i achieve it with query?

result columns would be like

```
+----+-------+---------------+
| id | name  | message_count |
+----+-------+---------------+
|  1 | One   |             1 |
|  3 | Two   |             4 |
|  4 | Three |            10 |
+----+-------+---------------+
```

I have tried with below query but didn't work

```
(SELECT U.id, U.name, COUNT(M.id) as message_count 
   FROM users U LEFT JOIN friends F 
     ON U.id = F.recipient_id LEFT OUTER JOIN messages M 
     ON  M.from_id = U.id 
    AND M.read_at IS NULL 
  WHERE F.sender_id = 2) 
UNION 
(SELECT U.id, U.name, COUNT(M.id) as message_count 
   FROM users U LEFT JOIN friends F 
     ON U.id = F.sender_id LEFT OUTER JOIN messages M 
     ON M.from_id = U.id 
    AND M.read_at IS NULL 
  WHERE F.recipient_id = 2) 
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Can anybody help me? Regards and Thank you all

Comment: = NULL does not work. Use `IS NULL`

Comment: Yes Question updated, still query not working

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re overcomplicating this. Something like this should work, although it’s hard to tell without the schematics of your tables:

```
SELECT U.id, U.name, COUNT(M.id) FROM users U 
INNER JOIN friends F 
ON (U.id = F.recipient_id AND F.sender_id = 2) 
   OR (F.recipient_id = 2 AND U.id = F.sender_id)
LEFT JOIN messages M
ON M.to_id = 2 AND M.from_id = U.id
WHERE M.read_at IS NULL
GROUP BY M.from_id
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Comment: Thanks man!! query works like charm except one thing. F.recipient_id = 2 AND U.id = F.sender_id ,

seems this part is not executing. Only gets that data which row has sender_id 2

Comment: @sagarpatel http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35bf18/1 Seems to work with how I suppose the schema looks. Have you replaced all occurrences of `2` with the ID you actually use?

Comment: yes i have, let me check & debug it again. Thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

if friends.recipient_id is your logged in user, something like this should work

```
SELECT
  users.name as friend_name, 
  COUNT(messages.id) as unread_messages_count
FROM
  friends
JOIN users on 
  users.id = friends.sender_id
LEFT JOIN messages on 
  messages.to_id = friends.recipent_id and
  read_at IS NULL
WHERE
  recipient_id = [logged user id]
```

Comment: No it could be sender_id as well